# Upgrading Reporting Services RLD 2005 --> 2008

Tags: reporting-services, upgrade, ssrs-2008, rdl

I ran the solution conversion for a bunch of reports I maintain, but a handful (about half a dozen) failed to convert.  I managed to convert some by hand, but some are different enough that changing the RDL by hand is difficult.  Is there a better way to fix these reports?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to open those file into SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio and save it again ?